# place the search button under below the input field

Tags: html, button, google-custom-search

I want to place the search button under te input field.
Is this possible ?

and how can this be done ?

I want to place this button under the input field because the input field is to small.

you can see wat i mean on http://www.dogsadoptionsnederland.nl
Look ad the left sidebar, there you can find the search engine.

Grtz from Holland,
M vd Waarsenburg.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with only css:

```
.gsc-search-button, .gsc-input {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, i put this code in the PHP file and it worked, is it also possible to center de button ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a little hack and inject CSS via jQuery in that element.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("table.gsc-search-box td").css( "display", "inherit" );
});
```

Result will be:

[image]

Note: There is no jQuery included in your website, so first you would have to include it like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```